# How to remove VisualStudio fonts green shadow?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using "Fixedsys Excelsior 3.01". I don't know why the fonts in "Sample" window looks fine but in the real editor's windows fonts are rendered with heave green shadow like the first picture.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably should run the ClearType tuner if it is too visible.  Or the font is just really poorly designed, having the red and blue anti-aliasing pixels overlap to produce green is not good.  Try Consolas first before doing anything radical.

Comment: @HansPassant But this font works fine in Notepad.exe with ClearType opened.

Comment: Hmya, Notepad does not use WPF or DirectWrite to render its text.  So that doesn't mean anything.  As I said, try Consolas to verify that there isn't anything drastically wrong with the text rendering engine.  If it looks good then ditch the font or contact the author of the font for support.

Comment: @HansPassant Consolas works fine either.